# Get a collection of functions in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-interop, excel-interop

Is there a way to get a collection of all of the functions that are currently available to Excel, including user-defined functions?

I am trying to create an application add-in that uses function usage information, so I need to be able to parse out Excel function calls in formulas.

Comment: The function's of a workbook ar split among a few areas I am not aware of any consolidated location, but you can loop through all modules for all sub and functions, user defined, you could loop all the worksheet functions also, if you need them but It would probably be much faster to just get a string list of all of them from online somewhere, also, you can loop through the dll functions using`Application.RegisteredFunctions` this will return function in DLL's along with some information on each function.

Comment: @user2140261 Ok, if there's not a single location, a list of all of the locations with how to access them would be good enough.

Comment: What about the autocomplete list? Is there a way to access that?

Comment: Are you expecting there to be any UDF's/Sub's or DLL's installed that will have functions? Or are you just speaking of the built in excel Worksheet function? And/Or vba methods and classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse out function names from formulas see my blog post on how to do it:
http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/parsing-functions-from-excel-formulas-using-vba-is-mid-or-a-byte-array-the-best-method/

If you want to find out information about built-in and XLL functions see this blog post
http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/finding-out-if-a-function-is-volatile-or-multithreaded-using-vba-udfs-for-udfs/

If you want to find out all available VBA UDF functions you could parse them out from the VBA if your code is allowed access to the VBA.

I don't know how to find available automation UDFs, they are not registered